# load data infile

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `class` with 3 fields named *id, password* and *name*.

Here this table is filled with 2 columns *id* and *password*.
I want to insert the `name column` alone using `load data infile` command in `MySql`.

Please give me an idea to insert only `name column` from the first row of the table using `load data infile` command for the table `class` mentioned above.

Comment: Read the whole file in to a table, then select out the column you want and dump the 1st table.

Comment: is your problem that you don't know how to structure the file, or that you don't know the syntax for the query (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)?

Answer (score 0):

myfile.txt:

```
john
"Betty Sue"
Felix
"Santa Claus"
```

query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.txt' 
  FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
INTO TABLE class(name);
```

Comment: I tried with above syntax but it's not updating from 1st row of table. The table class is already filled with id and password, here i need to insert the "name" values into table from CSV or text file from the first row of table. Please provide me the syntax.

Comment: @user1961616:  `LOAD DATA INFILE` cannot be used for `UPDATE` so far as I know.  What you'd need to do is create an empty temporary table with the same structure as your `class` table.  Do a `LOAD DATA INFILE` to the temporary table and then update your real `class` table.  Your `myfile.txt` would need to have at least one column that matched to existing data in the `class` table.